# Using AWS/S3 SDK v2 with client-side encryption in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, encryption

We are attempting to migrate our application to use AWS/S3 SDK v2.  To that end I've updated our maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.12</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

The changes are mostly obvious, but when we get to using client-side encryption, things are confusing.  I've found pages that talk about migrating the encryption client to V2:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/updates-to-the-amazon-s3-encryption-client/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/s3-encryption-migration.html

But the required classes like `AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2` do not exist in the SDK BOM.  Searching for the maven dependency, I can find https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-encryption-sdk-java/2.4.0, but that shows it is dependent on the v1 `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk` version 1.12.162.  Oddly, it also depends on the v2 `software.amazon.awssdk:kms`.

Now I am confused.  I feel like "SDK V2" and "encryption client V2" refer to a different "V2".  Did I find the right encryption artifact?  Can the v2 SDK be used with client-side encryption?  Do I just plow ahead and try it?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i have the same question ..

Comment: Maybe?  I did get some feedback from AMZN that a newer S3 encryption API had been developed but by then I'd moved on to other things.

Comment: i think i got it: github.com/aws/amazon-s3-encryption-client-java